# Gnome dash to dock extension minimize when you click, instead of shift+click

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, dock

My system is Ubuntu gnome 16.04 release (gnome 3.18 shell).

I am using Dash to Dock extension. When i click to any minimized programs (i click dock icon) it opens its windows as we want. However when i re-click to dock icon of any actually opened windows it doesn't minimize the opened program.

When i checked this out on the dash to dock's settings, to "minimize the windows" you have to do shift+click action. This "extra shift action" useless for me and i want to change it to simply click action.

How can i add this feature to dash to dock extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Tweak Tool > Extensions > Dash to Dock > [little gear icon settings thing] > Behaviour`, you can customise what the Click and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> actions do for any icon in the dock.

Answer (score 5):

goto tweak tool -> extensions -> dash to dock , press the gear icon ->  goto behavior tab -> there is something called 'click action' with a drop down menu and gear icon -> change the drop down menu action from 'cycle through windows' to 'minimize'.

Done. :)